# How do I block/prevent video downloader addins or programmes?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video site using a HTML5 video player. Users pay money to join the site. But the download manager (in mozilla) or real player download manager can download our videos from the server.

I want to prevent or block these applications. How can I prevent the programs from running?

Comment: I don't think you reliably can.

Answer (score 1):

There is no DRM ([Digital Rights Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)) in the HTML5 spec, so you cannot do it with HTML5 video.

There are attempts to add DRM to HTML 5 ([Encrypted Media Extensions](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html))

> With tech companies abandoning the proprietary Flash and Silverlight
>   media players for HTML5, it was inevitable somebody would try to
>   inject DRM into the virgin spec.
>
> Microsoft, Google and Netflix are that “somebody”, having submitted a
>   proposed modification to HTML5 to the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)
>   for “encrypted media extensions”.

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/02/23/microsoft_google_netflix_html5_drm_infection/

However, such extensions are not available today and will not be for some time, if indeed the proposal is even adopted.

If you need DRM, you will need to use a video technology that supports it.

Comment: thanx to answer but i have to give up a technology. Customer wants HTML5 and not be downloaded that not support it :)) it is problem. i persuasion customer one

Comment: It is a real problem (as the linked article points out).  Silverlight or Flash based solutions can provide DRM, but they are both end of life (though I guarantee they will be around especially for NetFlix clients until a better solution rolls along).  Keep in mind that many user's browsers don't support HTML 5 video.  If you use a technology to provide backward compatibility (e.g. http://html5media.info/), the will still inject something like Flash for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Even with DRM you simply can't - whatever you've sent to client (keys/content/whatever), client can simply save and replay when he needs decoded stream again. The only solution that would reliably **delay** decoding, is some hardware solution, but as I understand you'll be going over regular HTTP and browser.

Your problem is legal one and should be solved with legal means.

Comment: DRM **can** always be broken, but **not by most people most of the time**.  If you have a few hackers breaking DRM and redistributing videos illegally, you can go after them.  If every NetFlix user could just view their favorite movies and Save As to their XBox, NetFlix would see a surge of 1 month trial subscriptions that never convert to a paid subscription... There is a *reason* that NetFlix and others are so keen on DRM.  They know what happens in the real world and how it affects their pocketbook.

Comment: If you have a few hackers dumping ONE clean copy on some popular tracker, you'd have few millions of those "most people" redistributing it by the end of the day. Good luck going after them.

Comment: Oh but they do... https://www.google.com/search?q=recording+industry+lawsuits  If the distribution of DRM-broken copies happens online, people will be sued.  For lots of money.  If users can Save As in the privacy of their home, they are very unlikely to be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay their unique user ID onto the video, so if they do capture it, then legal action can be taken as you can prove it's them that downloaded it. 
other than that, nothing you can do really...